# SQL Joins (not repeat information)

Tags: sql, join, firebird, firebird2.5

I have two tables:

- T1: ASSEMBLYLINES (fields are ORDERNUMBER, LINECODE, ORDERQTY, SYSUNIQUEID)
- T2: ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES (Fields are ORDERNUMBER, COMPONENTCODE, ISSUEQTY, SYSUNIQUEID, HEADERSYSUNIQUEID)

In this example there is:

1 ASSEMBLYLINE record with the following information:

```
13088N03, 810044, 3, 12345678
```

3 ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES records with the following information:

```
13088N03, 810044, 1, 11234567, 12345678
13088N03, 810044, 1, 12234567, 12345678
13088N03, 810044, 1, 13234567, 12345678
```

My SQL Code is:

```
SELECT 
ASSEMBLYLINES.ORDERNUMBER, ASSEMBLYLINES.LINECODE, ASSEMBLYLINES.ORDERQTY, 
ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES.ORDERNUMBER, ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES.COMPONENTCODE, ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES.ISSUEQTY

FROM ASSEMBLYLINES
LEFT JOIN ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES ON ASSEMBLYLINES.SYSUNIQUEID = ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID
```

The result is:

```
ORDERNUMBER LINECODE    ORDERQTY    ORDERNUMBER2    COMPONENTCODE   ISSUEQTY
13088C33    800038            3         13088C33    800038             1
13088C33    800038            3         13088C33    800038             1
13088C33    800038            3         13088C33    800038             1
```

But this looks like 9 were ordered, but in fact only 3 were ordered. Is it possible to get a result that looks like:

```
ORDERNUMBER LINECODE    ORDERQTY    ORDERNUMBER2    COMPONENTCODE   ISSUEQTY
13088C33    800038            3         13088C33    800038             1
13088C33    800038                      13088C33    800038             1
13088C33    800038                      13088C33    800038             1
```

I can do two separate SQL's and then use Excel to create it, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

I don't want to use a SUM formula on the ISSUEQTY either.

*Thanks in advance. I tried to structure my question in a clear and concise manner, but a table would have helped with the result. Looks fine in the editor, but not in the result, so will try to look up how best to show that.

Comment: We are using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 2):

You can get your desired result by introducing a `CASE` and `row_number` in your query as below.

```
SELECT a.ORDERNUMBER,
       a.LINECODE,
       CASE
           WHEN row_number() over(partition BY a.ORDERNUMBER, a.LINECODE,b.ORDERNUMBER, b.COMPONENTCODE, b.ISSUEQTY
                                  ORDER BY a.ORDERNUMBER) = 1 THEN a.ORDERQTY
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Order_Quantity,
       b.ORDERNUMBER,
       b.COMPONENTCODE,
       b.ISSUEQTY
FROM ASSEMBLYLINES a
LEFT JOIN ASSEMBLYLINEISSUES b ON a.SYSUNIQUEID = b.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID;
```

**Result:**

```
ordernumber linecode    order_quantity  ordernumber  componentcode  issueqty
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
13088N03    810044          3            13088N03       810044         1
13088N03    810044                       13088N03       810044         1
13088N03    810044                       13088N03       810044         1
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/EESJOM49313)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Window functions (which includes `row_number`) are introduced in Firebird 3.

Answer (score 2):

The ROW_NUMBER() function was introduced with Firebird 3.0(see: [Window Functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html)), so you can't use it in Firebird 2.5. But you can use a temporary context variable using [stored procedure](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-procedure.html) or [execute block](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-execblock.html).  For example :

```
execute block
returns (
    ORDERNUMBER varchar(80),
    LINECODE integer,
    ORDERQTY integer,
    ORDERNUMBER1 varchar(80),
    COMPONENTCODE integer,
    ISSUEQTY integer)
as
declare variable tmp_str varchar(20);
BEGIN
  tmp_str='0'; /* Set temp variable to unavalable value */
  FOR
    select 
        assemblylines.ordernumber,
        assemblylines.linecode,
        assemblylines.orderqty,
        assemblylineissues.ordernumber,
        assemblylineissues.componentcode,
        assemblylineissues.issueqty
    from assemblylineissues
       right outer join assemblylines on (assemblylineissues.headersysuniqueid = assemblylines.sysuniqueid)
    INTO :ORDERNUMBER,
         :LINECODE,
         :ORDERQTY,
         :ORDERNUMBER1,
         :COMPONENTCODE,
         :ISSUEQTY
  DO
  BEGIN
    if (:tmp_str=:ordernumber) then
      orderqty = null; /* Set ORDER QTY to null if this is not the first selected record of ASSEMBLYLINES.ORDERNUMBER */
    tmp_str = :ordernumber;
    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```